# c# HttpWebRequest Returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send an [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) To a website .
the request is pretty simple :

```
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("");
        req.Host = "";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Accept = "";
        req.UserAgent =  "";
        req.Referer = "";
        var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

but i'm getting 403 Forbidden Exception .
what i cannot understand is the request works perfectly using requests captures tools like [Burpsuit](https://portswigger.net/burp) etc ...
I didnt forget anything about the request , the method and the host etc is correct . and the useragent is the latest :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

**the request Works** in my [rdp](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) which makes me think about the **sender IP** . but the issue is the request works with burpsuit and browsers as well .

any help ?

thanks

Comment: There still is a difference. Capture a working and not working request with for example Fiddler and compare them. Probably something with cookies.

Comment: @CodeCaster when sending a request with burpsuit i tried to send it without any cookie and it works .

Comment: Again, there still is a difference. Compare the requests. HTTP requests are entirely standalone, not influenced by their environment. The only thing that differs is the client's IP address. You're also talking about IP addresses; are you executing the requests from different clients?

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried the same request in my rdp (usa ip) and it works it receives response . but why burpsuit and browsers can receive response on my current IP ?

Comment: @MadScientist have you used the tool that Codecaster recommended yet? Fiddler? To capture and compare the HTTP requests?

Comment: if the website is IIS based, try looking at the substatus in the IIS log entry for the 403.